# Error in pivot_wider in R doubled: Values in `Data` are not uniquely identified; output will contain list-cols

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table, pivot, tidyr

I have tried different things I've seen in stackoverflow & can't quite solve the issue or understand why I'm having it.

I have a dataset like this:

```
council_name <- c("Barking and Dagenham","Barking and Dagenham","Barking and Dagenham","Barking and Dagenham","Barking and Dagenham","Barking and Dagenham","Barking and Dagenham","Barking and Dagenham","Barnet","Barnet")
period <- c("1st 2006", "1st 2006", "1st 2006", "1st 2006", "2nd 2006", "2nd 2006", "2nd 2006", "2nd 2006", "1st 2006", "1st 2006") 
category <- c ("glass", "fridges", "paper", "glass", "glass", "fridges", "paper", "glass", "glass", "fridges")
data <- c(333, 222, 100, 98, 450, 540, 33, 450, 560, 120)
category2 <- c ("collected", "collected", "collected", "no donors", "collected", "collected", "collected", "no donors", "collected", "collected")
df <- data.frame (council_name, period, category, category2, data)
```

And what I want is something like this:

```
council_name <- c("Barking and Dagenham","Barking and Dagenham","Barnet")
period <- c("1st 2006", "2nd 2006", "1st 2006") 
glass <- c(333, 450, 560)
fridges <- c(222,540,120)
paper <- c(100, 33, NA)
no.donors <- c(98, 450, NA)
df.desired <- data.frame (council_name, period, glass, fridges, paper, no.donors)
```

I've tried different things, like:

```
  df%>%
    distinct()%>%
    select(c(council_name,Period, Data, category1, category2))%>%
    pivot_wider(id_cols = c(council_name,Period),
              names_from = c(category1, category2),
              values_from = data)

#OR THIS 

waste %>%
  group_by(council_name) %>%
  mutate(row = row_number()) %>%
  pivot_wider(id_cols = c(council_name,Period),
              names_from = c(category1, category2),
              values_from = data)
```

But I keep on getting the following error:

```
"Values in `Data` are not uniquely identified; output will contain list-cols.
* Use `values_fn = list(Data = list)` to suppress this warning.
* Use `values_fn = list(Data = length)` to identify where the duplicates arise
* Use `values_fn = list(Data = summary_fun)` to summarise duplicates"
```

I tried checking where those duplicate values can be but it really makes no sense as each value of council_name*period has only one value of category1*category2. 
I tried other similar questions here but the solutions there didn't solve the issue for me.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) You don't need `category2`

2) There is no explanation of "no.donors" but based on your expected output it seems any `category` which repeats twice is given that value.

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
 select(-category2) %>%
 group_by(council_name, period, category) %>%
 mutate(category = ifelse(row_number() == 1, category, "no.donors")) %>%
 tidyr::pivot_wider(names_from = category,
                    values_from = data)


#  council_name         period   glass fridges paper no.donors
#  <chr>                <chr>    <dbl>   <dbl> <dbl>     <dbl>
#1 Barking and Dagenham 1st 2006   333     222   100        98
#2 Barking and Dagenham 2nd 2006   450     540    33       450
#3 Barnet               1st 2006   560     120    NA        NA
```

Comment: Thanks! But I get: "Error: Column `category` can't be modified because it's a grouping variable"

Comment: @AntVal Strange, it works fine for me though. Anyway, in that case you can use `df %>%
  group_by(council_name, period, category) %>%
  mutate(category2 = ifelse(row_number() == 1, category, "no.donors")) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  select(-category) %>%
  tidyr::pivot_wider(names_from = category2,
                     values_from = data)`